# How to commit a specific version of a file in svn?

Tags: svn

In a svn repository I want to commit a previous version of a file. Say, the repository is at revision 30000 and I want to commit a file `code.php` from revision 25000. I am not interested in revisions of this file between 25000 and 30000, I just want to commit the file `code.php` when it was at revision 25000.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
svn update -r25000 code.php
svn commit code.php
```

But this does not work! Neither `svn st` after the `svn update` shows anything, nor does the `svn commit` command. What am I missing here? How to create a revision 30001 of the repository in which just one file changed, namely `code.php`?

Additional information:
- svn version 1.7.9

Answer (score 1):

you reverse merge the file back to the old revision, then commit that:

```
svn merge -r HEAD:25000 code.php
svn diff code.php
svn commit code.php
```

Comment: When you svn up it marks the file in question as being at that revision and should not be considered 'different' from what's been checked out. if you ran an `svnversion .` it would have told you `25000:30000` i.e. you have code of mixed revisions in the working directory